# How To Define Table's Vertical Alignment

Tags: java, swt

Incredible easy question: I have a SWT table (viewer) and use a `SWT.MeasureItem` listener to set the cell height. How do I align the cell content to the bottom of the cell?

(It would probably work with another listener to `SWT.PaintItem` and some math and rendering all my cells manually, but that can't be the right way.)

```
public class TableDialog extends Dialog {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TableDialog dialog = new TableDialog(new Shell());
        dialog.open();
    }

    public TableDialog(Shell parent) {
        super(parent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureShell(Shell newShell) {
        super.configureShell(newShell);
        newShell.setText("Table Test");
        newShell.setSize(500, 300);
    }

    @Override
    protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
        Composite container = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
        container.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        TableViewer viewer = new TableViewer(container, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
        viewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
        viewer.setInput(Arrays.asList("A", "B", " C"));

        Table table = viewer.getTable();
        table.setLinesVisible(true);
        table.addListener(SWT.MeasureItem, e -> e.height = 90);

        return container;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you start using `SWT.MeasureItem` you need to do the drawing as well.

Since you are using `TableViewer` you can combine all this in one class by using an `OwnerDrawLabelProvider` as the viewer label provider. A very simple version would be something like this:

```
viewer.setLabelProvider(new OwnerDrawLabelProvider()
  {
    @Override
    protected void paint(final Event event, final Object element)
    {
      String text = element.toString();

      GC gc = event.gc;

      int textHeight = gc.textExtent(text).y;

      int yPos = event.y + event.height - textHeight;

      gc.drawText(text, event.x, yPos);
    }


    @Override
    protected void measure(final Event event, final Object element)
    {
      event.height = 90;
    }


    @Override
    protected void erase(final Event event, final Object element)
    {
      // Stop the default draw of the foreground
      event.detail &= ~SWT.FOREGROUND;
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid, `SWT.PaintItem` is the right way in this case.

One of the SWT Snippets demonstrates how to draw multiple lines in a table item. It may serve as a starting point for your custom drawing code:

http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet231.java

The [Custom Drawing Table and Tree Items](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-CustomDrawingTableAndTreeItems/index.html) article provides further information.